# Joint Uniform Distribution on a Square

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given a joint uniform distribution on a square where X ~ Uniform(0,1), Y ~ Uniform(0,1) and the event A = $\{(x,y) \vert xy \le 1\}$, then $P((X,Y) \in A) = 1.$

I've tried to work this out on paper by:

$P((X,Y) \in A)= \int_A f(x,y)dxdy$
$P(xy \le 1) = P(x \le \frac1y)= \int_0^1\int_0^{1/y}dxdy = ln1-ln0$

That's not 1. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restrict your integral to points where $x$ and $y$ are both in the interval $[0,1]$.  You have done this with the outer integral with respect to $y$ but not the inner integral: not every $x\in[0,1/y]$ is in $[0,1]$.  So $x$ should only go up to $1$ (not $1/y$, which is always greater than or equal to $1$) and you get $1$ for the integral (since you are just integrating over the square).

Comment: I get that since they are independent that both ranges should be zero to one but I'd expect the above equation to just work.

Is trying to find the range of one dimension just invalid due to independence? What about $P((X,Y) \in A)$ where $A =\{(x,y) \vert xy \le c, 0 \le c \lt 1\}$?

Comment: For example, $P(xy \le \frac12)$.

Comment: Another way to think about it is that your definition of $A$ was a bit imprecise.  The correct definition of $A$ is $\{(x,y)\color{red}{\in [0,1]^2}:xy\leq 1\}$, since your distribution is supported only on the square $[0,1]^2$.  So you need to find the correct bounds of integration for this set, including the restriction that $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$.

Comment: Or another way to think of it is, it is correct to integrate with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $1/y$, but you are integrating with respect to the uniform measure on $[0,1]$ (not on the whole real line).  That means instead of getting the length of the entire interval from $0$ to $1/y$, you only get the part of it that is actually in $[0,1]$.

Comment: I believe you're meaning $\int_0^1 \int_0^{min(\frac1y, 1)}dxdy$? For $A =\{(x,y) \vert xy \le \frac12 \}$, $P(xy \le \frac12) = \int_0^1 \int_0^{min(\frac{1}{2y}, 1)}dxdy$

Comment: Yes! This gave me the correct answer. Thanks.